# create an object under the condition from another object

Tags: c++

I have a `Login` class which logins a user. I have another class `window` which needs to create an object once the user logs in. The object is a window where user is given some menus and forms. I tried to do this with an `if` but the object is not available outside the if's scope.

login method from Login class:

```
Login::login(){
this->user = ui->user->text();
this->pass = ui->pass->text();
this->pass = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((pass.toLocal8Bit()),QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex());

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select pass from users where username =:user");
qry.bindValue(":user",this->user);
qry.exec();
while(qry.next()){
if(this->pass == qry.value(0).toString()){

            }

       }
```

In this method here. I want to create `window` class object if the password is matched. But the object needs to stay as long as it's destructor is called. How to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to *show* us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added code from Login class. I hope this helps.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it. Perhaps create your own class that owns the window object and pass a reference to that class to your `login` function. Perhaps have this function return a `std::unique_ptr<Login>`. Whatever makes sense in your code.

Comment: @David I created a `method` of `window` class which instantiates a `window` object. I called this method inside `if(this->pass == qry.value(0).toString())`. However I am not sure if there is a better way to do this? if you could explain unique_ptr. That would be of great help!